# Refactor two methods into one - Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the following method

```
const getLabel = data => {
  const { orderStatus, previousStatus } = data;
  const pdtLabel = {
    delivered: "Delivered at",
    admin_canceled: "Canceled at",
    approved_for_invoicing: getPdtLabel(previousStatus),
    cost_complete: getPdtLabel(previousStatus)
  };

  return pdtLabel[orderStatus]
     ? pdtLabel[orderStatus]
     : "Predicted delivery time";
};
```

the getPdtLabel method is as follows.

```
const getPdtLabel = status => {
  let pdtLabel;
  switch (status) {
    case "delivered":
      pdtLabel = "Delivered at";
      break;
    case "admin_canceled":
      pdtLabel = "Canceled at";
      break;
    default:
      pdtLabel = "Predicted delivery time";
  }
  return pdtLabel;
}
```

Is there a way we can refactor this? may be into a single method?

Comment: Can you describe in words what each method does (or what you want it to do)? And how that logic is shared?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to leave them seperated? Otherwise you could risk having your methods be too long. There is a StackExchange websites for these questions: [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does this code work? Your `pdtLabel` object doesn't have an `orderStatus` key, so it would always return "Predicted delivery time"